# blender 2.8 grease pencil channel not visible in viewport

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil

I was animating two different characters in each of its channel using grease pencil in blender 2.8.

suddenly I got stuck in the following issues:

1. I am unable to change or select between channels and draw new frames.
2. One of the channels is not visible in the viewport or in dopesheet, but I can see in the "view layer" panel under scene collections.
3. In the object data of the grease pencil channel it shows"multi user data block not supported".

Comment: Did you by any chance create a new scene? Because I had problems with grease pencil when I create a new scene (at least as a full copy, haven't tried other scenarios).

Comment: i was using grease pencil on a 3d environment. so, yes i created a seperate scene collection(animation)  for grease pencil.

Comment: Are you sure you mean a scene? Sounds you're talking about workspace (animation). In my case, if I create a new scene, and in object mode switch to another object, I wouldn't be able to select the grease pencil object anymore, I believe grease pencil (as many other features) are still under development. Expect to find lots of bugs when working with Blender 2.8, since it's still in Beta.

Comment: yes, in my case its the same scene . Also in the animation workspace, Im unable to switch between grease pencil channels(i guess, i'm not sure). i drew  around 90 frames  in one of the two grease pencil channel. all of the them are gone. when i select the channel  in the "view layer " panel. it shows "multi-user data not supported" under the object data->onion skin option in properties panel. how retrive the lost frames.  because i can see the layer in the view layers.